# Improve the code of an algorithm of combinations

Tags: java, memory, time, space

I realized this algorithm for generating combinations. It works in the following way, if we have the input:

> [A, B, C]

The combinations will be

> [A], [B], [C]. [A, B], [A, C], [B, C], [A, B, C].

While if we have in input:

> [1,1,2,3]

The combinations will be:

> [1], [2], [3], [4], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3 ], [1,1,2,3].

However, this algorithm has a running time of good only when the input is a list of size 4, if the list is of size 5 or more the program stops and gives me `java.lang.OutOfMemory` (I increased the memory for in java). One problem could be the fact that I have used `LinkedList`, but I'm not sure.

Is there a better solution?

```
private List<Elemento> combinazioneMassima = new ArrayList<>();
private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Combinazioni3.class);

public Combinazioni3(List<Elemento> generaCombinazioneMassima) {
    this.combinazioneMassima = generaCombinazioneMassima;
}

public void combine() {
    this.findAllCombinations(combinazioneMassima);
}

private static class Node{
    int lastIndex = 0;
List<Elemento> currentList;
public Node(int lastIndex, List<Elemento> list) {
        this.lastIndex = lastIndex;
        this.currentList = list;
}
public Node(Node n) {
        this.lastIndex = n.lastIndex;
        this.currentList = new ArrayList<Elemento>(n.currentList);
}
}

public void findAllCombinations(List<Elemento> combinazioni) {
    Date dataInizio = new Date();
    List<List<Elemento>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<Elemento>>();
    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
    int n = combinazioni.size();
    ArrayList<Elemento> temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
    temp.add(combinazioni.get(0));
    queue.add(new Node(0, temp));
    // add all different integers to the queue once.
    for(int i=1;i<n;++i) {
            if(combinazioni.get(i-1) == combinazioni.get(i)) continue;
            temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
            temp.add(combinazioni.get(i));
            queue.add(new Node(i, temp));
    }
    // do bfs until we have no elements
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node node = queue.remove();
            if(node.lastIndex+1 < n) {
                    Node newNode = new Node(node);
                    newNode.lastIndex = node.lastIndex+1;
                    newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(node.lastIndex+1));
                    queue.add(newNode);
            }
            for(int i=node.lastIndex+2;i<n;++i) {
                    if(combinazioni.get(i-1) == combinazioni.get(i)) continue;
                    // create a copy and add extra integer
                    Node newNode = new Node(node);
                    newNode.lastIndex = i;
                    newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(i));
                    queue.add(newNode);
            }
            GestoreRegole gestoreRegole = new GestoreRegole();
            gestoreRegole.esegui(node.currentList);
    }

}
```

Comment: If your looking for suggestions on ways to improve the performance of your code, and your code s working, then this is a question for codereview.stackexchange.com and not a StackOverflow question!

Comment: What are you trying to do in `while` loop? can you write some comments.

Comment: They realize the combinations . In practice with the linked list I hold the reference to the previous node and the next in-law and I all combinations

Comment: @JamesZafar: If OP gets OOM for a list with 5 elements, I'd suggest to classify this code as "not working". 5 elements means 120 permutations, and as I understand the question results with fewer than the number of input elements should be counted, leading to an upper limit of 720 combinations (sorry, I don't want to waste time to think about the actual number which is less than that). However, that should surely fit into memory.

Comment: Excuse me, I expressed myself badly , I get the java.lang.OutOfMemory when there are 5 different elements ( for example 80 A, 150 B , 80 C , 30 D , 20 E)

Comment: Why does the output for [1,1,2,3] contain [4]? and why doesn't it contain [1,1] and [1,2,3]?

Comment: @Elke You are quite right , there are also these outputs

Comment: @pasq do you understand that when there are `n` elements, you have to print `2 power n` combinations(all subsets) ?

Comment: Of course I know, but how can I fix this?